# Need to boot Linux Mint install DVD on MacPro 1,1

Tags: linux, mac, linux-mint

I have been banging my head on this one for a long time.  I can't get any of the ISOs provided by Linux Mint to boot on CD.  USB is not an option for a MacPro this old.  The only thing I've been able to accomplish is getting the Gentoo Mininmal Installation CD to run, but I'd rather use Mint if possible, and I really don't want to have to compile a kernel.

I have rEFIt installed and I'm dual booting windows.  I got Mint installed, but it's version 9 and it runs under Windows.  It has to be possible to get the DVD to boot, but I can't figure it out.

I would settle for Ubuntu, or even Gentoo if I didn't have to compile my own kernel.  I can do it, but I don't want to spend that much time just getting Linux running on my mac.

I don't want to virtualize.

Answer (score -1):

if ubuntu a choise, then use the iso with +mac. and you must use the 14.04.4-iso and then upgrade to 16.04 (i was doing the same, but i would likely arch on my mac). runs fine with ubutu, but mint never used. i think your end is the same as mine:
1.
2.
select cd-rom boot type:_
and frozen black screen.